# How can I make MS visual studio support Smalltalk?

Tags: visual-studio, smalltalk

How can I make **MS visual studio** support **Smalltalk** ?

Comment: What level of support are you trying to achieve?  Editor colorization?  Completion?  Debugger?

Comment: Learn Visual Studio Extensibility, and then write your own SmallTalk extension.

Comment: @LexLi it is written Smalltalk with a lowercase t. Just trying to avoid the spreading of the wrong spelling.

Answer (score 2):

*Hey, guys. I have finally found one that might help.*

**[Smalltalk language support for VS Code]**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PleasedSkin.smalltalk

Comment: Your original question just said "Visual Studio" which is a full development/build/debug environment. Visual Studio Code is a code editor. Is that all you wanted?